# How is an instance of a parent component passed into a child component constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to understand how the table component works in PrimeNG.  I'm confused as to how an instance of a parent component is passed into the constructor of the child component.

Here is the source to the TableBody component taking in an instance of the Table component. [PrimeNG Table Source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/32cd5ebb779f1c95ecd8803cf5af909ca9d04bc0/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L2204)

So my understanding is that the TableBody component has an attribute as the selector.  It is passed in the columns and bodyTemplate from the parent (Table) component. Now what I don't understand is how an instance of the parent component (Table) is passed into it when it is created.

Snippet of the Table component template

```
            <div class="ui-table-wrapper" *ngIf="!scrollable">
            <table #table [ngClass]="tableStyleClass" [ngStyle]="tableStyle">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="colGroupTemplate; context {$implicit: columns}"></ng-container>
                <thead class="ui-table-thead">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerTemplate; context: {$implicit: columns}"></ng-container>
                </thead>
                <tfoot *ngIf="footerTemplate" class="ui-table-tfoot">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="footerTemplate; context {$implicit: columns}"></ng-container>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody class="ui-table-tbody" [pTableBody]="columns" [pTableBodyTemplate]="bodyTemplate"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Full Source: [Github source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/32cd5ebb779f1c95ecd8803cf5af909ca9d04bc0/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L58)

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes [pTableBody] and [pTableBodyTemplate] has in the parent component has declared @Input in the ts file.
And the "columns" is binded to a variable with the same name.

Read a bit about Input and Output https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/

Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Ollpej - Yes, I understand how the input/output decorator works but this is not how the instance of the Table component is pass into the TableBody component. Its done via the constructor.

Comment: The constructor is used to load Services and not components.
 constructor(private logger: LoggerService)

The outside the constructor we can use the logger variable to access functions in LoggerService.ts

Comment: I get what you are saying but did you look at the github source?  Its a component being pass in the constructor.